# Check if application is going to background and close my dialog(if any)

Tags: android

I need to check if my application is going to background due to Home,power or any other event causing the application to go into background. Based on this event I have to close all the dialogs(if shown). My app also support orientation change and I have to retain dialog(if shown) in case of orientation change.

**Things I tried**: I have tried methods mentioned on the below blogs but it's fails in orientation change.
http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.in/2013/05/android-solution-to-detect-when-android.html

Most of the Stackoverflow suggestion fails on orientation change.

**EDIT**
More information about my app so that could help.
My activity has Tabs and a container, which get replace with Fragment on tab click. Every fragment has different layout for landscape and portrait. Even the activity layout is different for landscape and portrait.

Answer (score 1):

override your onPause method to insure that any open dialog is closed before it goes to background

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (alertDialog != null) {
        alertDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't do it since I have to retain my dialog in case of orientation change.

Answer (score 0):

On onPause dismiss all your dialogs:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (dialog!= null) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

also if you want to handle orientation change then add this line in your activity tag in manifest:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

this will override the default behavior of android's orientation change.

Comment: Can't do it since I have to retain my dialog in case of orientation change. And I can't put configChanges in Manifest as I have different layout for my activity.

Comment: " I have different layout for my activity"  what do you mean by that?

Comment: One layout xml for portrait and other layout xml for landscape. I have edited my question to add more information about my app.

Comment: so what is the problem then override the method onConfigurationChanged () and inside that method set the layout according to the portrait or landscape orientation using setContentView();

Comment: What about the fragment inside the activity? I have to set their layout as well and I have multiple fragments. Don't you think it's overkill and increases complexity. Beside including configChanges in Manifest is a hack and Google don't recommend doing it as there are tons of ways configChange could happen.